# How do I make an entity move once per second in crafty.js

Tags: javascript, grid, crafty

I am trying to implement "Snake" using crafty.js but I can't seem to get the snake entity to move just once in a second. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the timeout method from Crafty core functions.

First argument is the function to be executed, second argument is the time in miliseconds

```
Crafty.c("Snake",{
  init: ...
  move: function() {
      //code for movement
      this.timeout(move, 1000);
  }
});
```

or you can pass an anonymus function as argument

```
this.timeout(function() {
//code code coode
}, 1000);
```

source: 
http://craftyjs.com/api/Crafty-Core.html#-timeout

*Sorry if i my English is bad*

Comment: I must have missed this in the documentation. Thank you for pointing it out.